# Removing app from real device after testing

Tags: android

I'm developing with AndroidStudio  and I'm using my personal android phone for testing my apps.

How is the correct way of unisntall or remove the app after I run it on the real device?

Is there an option on AndroidStudio?

Or I just need to uninstall it just like regular apps from PlayStore?

Couldnt find an answer on the web. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can just uninstall them just as the same as regular apps

Comment: see https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521768?hl=en-IN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line/terminal:

```
adb uninstall com.example.yourpackagename
```

Or from the device, uninstall in Settings | Apps.

Comment: You can probably even add this as a custom command in most IDEs, though making it automatically figure out the package name will be neat trick (if the IDE doesn't have a variable for that, you could grep it out of your manifest)

Comment: Thank you. Im developing on Android for about 2 weeks. Didn't know about adb.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in the IDE, and I don't see why there should be?

Simply uninstall the app from Settings -> Apps, or from your launcher, or from command line using adb uninstall <packagename>, or from whatever works best for you.